# Instantiating UIView subclass loaded from xib

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIView subclass which I load from a xib file. In my CustomView.h file, I simply ignore the CGRect parameter in the initWithFrame: method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return self;
}
```

Now my question is this: **Whenever I instantiate my custom view, what is the frame I should be passing?**

For instance, I tried this:

```
CustomView *cv = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

One would assume that because the frame was set in xib, it wouldn't matter what is passed here. However, this causes my custom view to be unresponsive to user interaction.

Comment: That is not how loadNibNamed works.  I'm surprised this doesn't cause crashes.  The return type is an NSArray of root level objects.  If you actually want an object to use them, you have to set an owner.  P.S. Don't do it like this, it's soooo weird.

Comment: What would be a better way? Can you elaborate? How else would you create a custom view in xib and use it in your view controllers?

Comment: You don't need to worry about it.  That is the point of a XIB file.  You usually instantiate a *view controller* not a *view*.  You can create a view controller using initWithNibName:bundle:  You can change the class of your view in the XIB.  If you don't know how, there is lots of info out there for you to study.  After that if you want some custom initialization, you can override initWithCoder: as the answer below did.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use initWithCoder instead

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self){
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example of initWithCoder wrt UIViews?

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you are trying to do? There are several ways to load views in Cocoa, and the best method depends on the structure of your app and of what you need done.